# NS what to type in while registering domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I want to register a domain name, so they asked me to type in 2 NS-servers, I want to use my BIND server for that. I've got static IP, let it be xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. If I type in my xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx into NS1 during registration I get an error:

```
{ns1=NameServer xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx should be in proper format}
```

So how to manage this situation?

P.S. I'm not a professional sys. administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registrar will need to know the necessary information to delegate your zone to your nameservers of choice.

Delegation is done by adding `NS` records in the parent zone and the value of `NS` records are the **names of the nameservers**.

If the names of your nameservers are inside the zone that is being delegated the registrar will also need the IP addresses so that they can add glue `A`/`AAAA` records that will be returned with the `NS` records in responses with authority information for your zone. Otherwise that is not needed as the names can just be resolved normally.

You will have to decide what the names of your nameservers are but these names must have `A` and/or `AAAA` records that point to the IP addesses of your nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

Some registrar asks for the hostname instead of IP address. Your name server should therefore have an `A` record like `ns.example.com`.

Comment: All registrars ask for the hostnames of the nameservers. The IP addresses are only required in situations where they need to add `A`/`AAAA` glue records in addition to the `NS` records.